# how do we read this sentence '50X better software quality'

Tags: pronunciation

I am browsing a website. There is one sentence:

> 50x better software quality

here *x* should mean *times*, but I don't know how to read it. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: not sure what you are asking - pls clarify.

Comment: ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: That should have read “50× better”, not “50x better”.

Comment: The 50x may be a riff on some current slang for describing speedy coders: "So, you're a 10x developer or a 25x programmer..." http://developers.slashdot.org/story/13/04/11/2216236/top-coders-tell-agents-show-me-the-money?utm_source=rss1.0mainlinkanon&utm_medium=feed In *that* context, it's "10 ex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read

> Fifty times better software quality

(But, just because we can read it, we cannot conclude it makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "50x better" implies some sort of metric for quality, perhaps the relative infrequency of "bugs" or better achievement of project goals. @WayfaringStranger has pointed us to an example where the construction is being used (and the exact meaning is disputed in some of the comments.) @Kris is likewise pointing out, somewhat elliptically, that this is arguably not an English language issue, but rather a geekish-language concern.